# Raspberry pi connect to internet using commandline/python script

Tags: wifi, pi-zero-w

I have a Raspberry-Pi zero w and I want to connect it to the internet using a python script. I know the network ESSID and Password. Is there any python library that can do this?
Is there any way I can do it via command line? If there is, I can use the subprocess library to execute that command. I have used the following command but it doesnt seem to work:

sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid NETWORKID key s:PASSWORD

It seems to run successfully without any errors but it doesn't connect the raspberry-pi to the internet.

I know I can use nmcli, but for some reason, I am avoiding it. Is there any other way I can connect to the internet using a python script/commandline?

Comment: You probably COULD - but WHY? See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) NOTE Raspbian DOES NOT use nmcli and other obsolete methods are incompatible with `dhcpcd`

Comment: I need to run a python program which reads ESSID and password from a file, checks whether the the connected wifi is the same as that read from the file, and reconnects if its not. The link you gave above is for network configuration.

Comment: Your comment does not explain what you want to do - also **Paste additional detail into your question**. You can put as many networks as you like into wpasupplicant and set priorities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Raspberry Pi we use **wpa_supplicant** for wifi. It has a command line interface called `wpa_cli`. With it you can do almost all with wpa_supplicant including get/set network and set identity and password. I would start wpa_supplicant on boot up as usual because `wpa_cli` wants to connect to a running daemon. Then you should be able to compare and reconnect the network with `wpa_cli` also by script.

Comment: `dhcpcd` starts `wpa_supplicant` through its `10-wpa_supplicant` hook

Comment: @Milliways Yes, but it is completely isolated running outside the init system. `systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service` shows a dead and disabled service. Very confusing.